# custom date format in django

Tags: django, date, format

I use in my proyect `l10n` with custom date formats, like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT = r'Y\k\o F\r\e\n d\a'
```

so the current date is shown like this:

```
2014ko Apirilaren 08a
```

but the problem is that the suffix depend on the last letter of the month, for example:

```
bbbb -aren
aaaa -ren
```

if the month ends in consonant, the suffix is "aren", but if the month ends in vowel, is "ren", and I don't know how to do that.